# Regression for a discrete variable

Tags: neural-networks, regression

I'm building a model (neural net) that would predict a quality score for images.

Ground truth is given by a 4-level discrete variable (0%, 33%, 67%, 100%), and I would like to build a model that would give something that looks like a continuous result over the 0-100% scale.

What should I pay attention to?

What I'm afraid of is that the model might stick to ground-truth levels and prefer them over any value in between.

Comment: This sounds like you'd be better of treating this as a classification problem. Maybe try having 2 outputs, one for "good" and one for "bad", then treat them as a probability (ie, softmax). This will ensure you are bounded in the 0-100% range, and would also likely mean (assuming you don't over-train) it will predict continuously

Comment: I'm afraid that softmax would push the predictions towards the edges (0 and 100) and the distribution will come out very non-uniform.

Comment: It doesn't do this if used properly, take a look at some image classifiers, you'll notice that with ambiguous images the network will often output low-confidence scores. If you train the network properly it shouldn't approach extremes. Ultimately, you'll find the best luck with experimenting though, so just start trying a bunch of things until it works